# How to print null values in the JSON rest webservice response in Java?

Tags: java, json, web-services, rest, jdeveloper

I have the below method in my rest service test class.

```
@Override
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS)
@GET
@Produces("application/json")
@Path("/list")
public List<XXX> findAll() {
    System.out.println("inside wrapper class findall");
    return super.findAll();
}
```

The JSON response does not print any null value fields in the response.

e.g.- It prints `{"key":"1","value:2"}` instead of `{"key":1, "value":2, "dvalue":null}`

I tried using `@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS)` but that is not working either.  I am using `jackson-annotations-2.0.4 jar`.

Please let me know what might I be missing.

Comment: The annotation must be on the class XXX, not on the findAll method.

Comment: How does a list print key-value pairs?

Comment: @JB Nizet- I added the annotation to the class but its still not working